# Target a specific iframe ID?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have a page that has multiple youtube videos. I want the video to play when someone clicks on the link that corresponds to each video.

For Example: When someone clicks on the video 2 link, video 2 plays.

HTML

```
   <!-- This loads the YouTube IFrame Player API code -->
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1"
  frameborder="0"></iframe>
<a href="#" id="start">Video 1</a>

<br><hr>

<!-- This loads the YouTube IFrame Player API code -->
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

<iframe id="ytplayer2" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/WdkT4_OJ2WU?enablejsapi=1"
  frameborder="0"></iframe>
<a href="#" id="start">Video 2</a>
```

JQUERY

```
    var ytplayer;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    ytplayer = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {

    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#start").click(function () {
        ytplayer.playVideo();
    });
});
```

**[HERE IS MY JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dSqF4/68/)** Only clicking on video 1 works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dSqF4/76/) that works as you expected.

I have removed the second script tag and modified the ids of the second iframe and a tags.

```
var ytplayer, ytplayer2;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    ytplayer = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {});
    ytplayer2 = new YT.Player('ytplayer2', {});
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#start").click(function () {
        ytplayer.playVideo();
        return false;
    });
    $("#start2").click(function () {
        ytplayer2.playVideo();
        return false;
    });
});
```

The html part:

```
<!-- This loads the YouTube IFrame Player API code -->
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?enablejsapi=1"
  frameborder="0"></iframe>
<a href="#" id="start">Video 1</a>

<br><hr>

<iframe id="ytplayer2" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/WdkT4_OJ2WU?enablejsapi=1"
  frameborder="0"></iframe>
<a href="#" id="start2">Video 2</a>
```

Hope this helps.